# using dd for clean MBR code doesn't work on pfSense

Tags: partition, freebsd, dd, disk, mbr

Trying to clean the mbr code part on a disk using the pfsense 2.7.0 live disk (pfsense is based on freebsd) under shell command.

being **/dev/da0** my drive following the suggested code for clean just the mbr code keeping the partitions the command should be:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/da0 bs=446 count=1
```

however... the result is:

```
dd: /dev/da0: Invalid argument
1+0 records in
0+0 records out
0 bytes transferred in 0.000089 secs (0 bytes/sec)
```

instead... if I use as code just `dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/da0` it just erases everything without errors :(

I'm doing this tests in a vm so I can recover the hd many times to test this passage... however this thing is giving me headaches...

**EDIT:** It seems that if I use `bs=512` or `bs=1M` it doesn't gives errors. However doing so also the partitions table part would be deleted...

**EDIT2:** I tried to use the command `dd if=/dev/da0 of=/tmp/mbr_file bs=512 count=1` and it create for me a file with the mbr, I wonder what commands can I use for edit in binary mode the file filling the first 446 bytes with 0 and then use `dd if=/tmp/mbr_file of=/dev/da0 bs=512 count=1` to restore it.

What could I use? vi?

Comment: It's been a very long time since I used a BSD. However, is `/dev/da0` a block device or a character device? If it's a character device you may still have to write full blocks (or multiples)

Comment: Same thought here. Can you make a block-sized all-zero file and `cat thatfile > /dev/da0`?

Comment: @MarcusMüller at end of the Question the OP says that's possible. So I think we're up for reading a block, overwriting the first 446 bytes, and writing it back again

Comment: @roaima yeah I guess that could be the strategy to follow, can you post it as a reply below with the list of commands to execute? thank you very much, I'm not very fond of BSD and want to do it in a secure way.

Comment: @MarcusMüller can you explain how to do that? I tried randomly `touch something` and `cat something > /dev/da0` it doesn't write anything in console that makes you understand if the command worked or not. But if I fill **something** with some random data (not sure what amount of characters) and try to repeat  `cat something > /dev/da0` it says: `cat: stdout: Invalid argument`

Comment: So, roaima was right, you already basically did what I describe. The point is that you can only write block sized to that block device. So you'd have to read the full first block from your da0 to a file, then overwrite the first 446 bytes in the file, then write that file over the first block

Comment: You can use `gpart destroy` to remove MBR.

Comment: @arrowd but I want to keep the last 66 bytes of the first 512 bytes block containing the partition table! otherwise `dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/da0 bs=512 count=1` would have sufficed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, I did many test and came to this conclusion...

Because pfsense is a damn stripped version of freebsd and LOT of tools are missing I had to do this to clear the first 446 byes in the disk preserving the partition table located at the latest 66 bytes of the first 512 bytes block.

```
dd if=/dev/da0 of=/tmp/mbr_file_original bs=512 count=1
dd if=/dev/zero of=/tmp/mbr_file_zerofilled bs=446 count=1
cat /tmp/mbr_file_original | ( dd of=/dev/null bs=446 count=1; dd bs=66 count=1 ) > /tmp/mbr_file_partitions_table
cat /tmp/mbr_file_partitions_table >> /tmp/mbr_file_zerofilled
mv /tmp/mbr_file_zerofilled /tmp/mbr_file_new
dd if=/tmp/mbr_file_new of=/dev/da0 bs=512 count=1
```

then for testing the copied mbr content

```
dd if=/dev/da0 of=/tmp/mbr_file_test bs=512 count=1
hexdump /tmp/mbr_file_test | less
```

In short what I did is:

- copy the mbr to a mbr_file_original
- created a zero filled 446 bytes file called mbr_file_zerofilled
- then BECAUSE SOMEONE YEAH I'M LOOKING AT YOU removed practically every useful tool even hex editors, leaving just this hack available used this line `cat mbr_file | ( dd of=/dev/null bs=446 count=1; dd bs=66 count=1 ) > mbr_file_partition_table` to extract from original mbr_file the last 66 bytes.
- At this point using cat I concat 2 files and renamed to a mbr_file_new for the sake of clarity and then used dd to save back the mbr to the da0 device

this time without errors because I used 512 bytes in one time.

Answer (score 5):

It's been a very long time since I last used a BSD system, and my memory of them regarding disk devices is that you must write full blocks (or multiples). It seems that this is still the case, and in particular for `/dev/da0`.

The general approach is to read a block, update the relevant part of it, and then write the full block back again. Here, we'll keep a backup of the original block too, as `block0.backup`:

```
dd if=/dev/da0 bs=512 count=1 | tee block0.backup >block0
dd if=/dev/zero bs=446 count=1 conv=notrunc of=block0
dd if=block0 bs=512 of=/dev/da0
```

(This is one of the rare situations where `dd` really is required, rather than `cat`.)

If you need to revert to the backup,

```
dd if=block0.backup bs=512 of=/dev/da0
```

Comment: Wise to include making a backup copy!

Answer (score 3):

Several answers have correctly pointed out that one writes characters to character devices, and blocks to block devices.

I don't know what tools pfSense includes and which it omits, but on a full-featured FreeBSD system, the following would work:

I'll write a sample `/boot/pmbr` image to my test disk `/dev/md0` and use that as a starting point:

```
# gpart bootcode -b /boot/pmbr md0
bootcode written to md0
```

That makes the first block of `md0` look like:

```
# dd if=/dev/md0 count=1 | hexdump -v
1+0 records in
1+0 records out
512 bytes transferred in 0.000053 secs (9723673 bytes/sec)
0000000 31fc 8ec0 8ec0 8ed8 bcd0 0e00 1abe bf7c
0000010 061a e6b9 f301 e9a4 8a00 fa80 7280 8a0b
0000020 7536 8004 80c6 f238 0272 80b2 d1e8 b600
0000030 bb01 0e00 91be e807 00ac 8166 003e 450e
0000040 4946 7520 660d 3e81 0e04 4150 5452 0275
...
00001a0 be11 000b 6015 4fb8 900f 9090 9090 9090
00001b0 9090 9090 9090 9090 0000 0000 0000 0000
00001c0 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
00001d0 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
00001e0 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
00001f0 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 aa55
0000200
```

To create a zeroed MBR boot record, I'll copy the `pmbr` image:

```
# cp -vp /boot/pmbr mbr.zeroed
/boot/pmbr -> mbr.zeroed
```

And use `hexedit` to put zeros at offsets 0x0-0x1b7.
<kbd>Ctrl-X</kbd> <kbd>Y</kbd> to save and exit.

Finally, I'll tell `gpart` to write that file back to the MBR.

```
# gpart bootcode -b mbr.zeroed md0
bootcode written to md0
```

And now we have:

```
# dd if=/dev/md0 count=1 | hexdump -v
1+0 records in
1+0 records out
512 bytes transferred in 0.000106 secs (4847613 bytes/sec)
0000000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000010 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000020 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000030 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000040 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
...
00001a0 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
00001b0 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
00001c0 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
00001d0 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
00001e0 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
00001f0 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 aa55
0000200
```

Comment: And as the OP stated that a "live disk" was used he could probably have found a more full featured live disk. One of the official FreeBSD images, mfsBSD, Damn Small BSD etc.

Comment: @ClausAndersen thanks for pointing out various live freebsd based distros! I had to use pfsense because have not available more empty CDs and that one was already recorded.